# Как сделать хлебные крошки на php?

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте! У меня сайт на базе mysql. Интересует Как сделать хлебные крошки на php(типа такого: Главная>Новости>Погода...и т.д.)?
В инете много таких крошек для cms, а у меня самописный сайт. Буду рад любой помощи. Спасибо.

Comment: Как вариант - соблюдать родителя, используя который выводить название странички! В общем, если система самописька нормально продумана, реализовать несложно... Если самописька не досконально реализована, нужно дореализовывать ее всегда!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как-то делал давно.

**Обработчик крошек:**

```
function navigation() {
    $arg_list = func_get_args();
    $numargs = func_num_args();
    $str = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numargs; $i++) {
        $str .= ($arg_list[$i][1] ? 
                    ($arg_list[$i][0] ? 
                        '<a href="' . $arg_list[$i][0] . '">' . $arg_list[$i][1] . '</a>' : 
                        $arg_list[$i][1]
                    ) . ($numargs - 1 > $i && $arg_list[$i][0] ? 
                            '<span>›</span>' : 
                            ''
                        ) : ''
                );
    }

    return $str;
}
```

**Использование:**

```
echo navigation(
    array('/', 'Главная'), 
    array('/old', 'Чуток ниже'), 
    array('/old-s', 'И еще чуток ниже')
);
```

**Результат:**

```
<a href="/">Главная</a><span>›</span><a href="/old">Чуток ниже</a><span>›</span><a href="/old-s">И еще чуток ниже</a>
```

Естественно HTML-код можно изменить как нужно.

---

Да, функция кривая и бла бла бла. Еще Месси 5 голов забил, ага.

Answer (score 1):

Делал когда-то используя Nested Sets. Преимущество - не надо у каждого родителя спрашивать родителя или таскать за собой всю связку id-шников, а только зная 1 id получай всю ветку разом

Comment: ссылка на статью протухла (( удалил.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Определяем переменную parent_id
$parent_id = isset($_GET['parent_id']) ? $_GET['parent_id'] : null;

function breadcrumb($cat, $parent_idid){
//Проверяем что parent_ID это число
if(!intval($parent_idid)) return false;

//Создаем пустой массив
$brc = array();

//Перебираем полученый массив с меню
for($i = 0; $i < count($cat); $i++){
    //Проверяем что мы не нашли родителя и не массив пуст
    if($parent_id != 0 and !empty($cat[$parent_id])){
        //Ищем родителя
        $brc[$cat[$id]['parent_id']] = $cat[$parent_id]['title'];
        $parent_id = $cat[$parent_id]['parent'];
    }
    //Останавливаем цикл
    else break;
}
//Возвращаем перевернутый массив с сохранением ключей
return array_reverse($brc, true);
}
```