# Как сделать хлебные крошки на php mvc?

Tags: php, mvc

Делаю пробный сайт по системе mvc. Есть модели, контроллер, роутер. Как сделать хлебные крошки? Помогите пожалуйста. Как их написать и куда пихать?

**Обновление**

Проблема такая - нужно вывести хлебные крошки. Я пытаюсь написать эти крошки...но я пока не понимаю, в какой файл их класть и следовательно, как составить эти крошки. Мне кажется, нужно что то в роутере сделать)) Я хочу, чтобы при нажатии на категорию и (или) на продукт, у меня выводились хлебные крошки, "пройденного пути".

Comment: Вы делаете в фреймворке? Yii, Symfony там? Если так - посмотрите в документации по фреймворку "breadcrumbs" (хлебные крошки на английском)

Comment: Я так понял что "нет без фреймворка". Т.е. Вы с нуля сделали структуру MVC? Лучше используйте существующие фреймворки, они ОЧЕНЬ облегчат Вам жизнь (если, конечно, это не боевой проект, который нужно будет сначала переписать). Там и хлебные крошки, роутинг настраиваемый, и всё красиво (если выбрать хороший фреймворк).

Comment: Я новичек в php..и мне нужно как то самому все сделать))

Comment: Возможно не совсем корректно с моей стороны, т.к. я не гуру PHP и с PHP не работаю уже больше года, но лучше смотрите как сделано в классных проектах-фреймворках (Laravel5, Yii2, Symfony3), учитесь сразу делать правильно (конечно прям сразу не получится, но всё же). Все равно в реальных проектах вы с вероятностью 95% будете использовать какой-то фреймворк. Я за 5 лет ниразу не использовал самописные системы. Разобраться с PHP Вы сможете и на основе фреймворка. Если сложно - подтяните ООП, потом опять за фреймворк)

Answer (score 2):

По сабжу - на основе самописной системы сложно прям точно сказать, что Вам нужно сделать. 
Посмотрите как реализовано в [Yii2](http://www.webapplex.ru/vizdzhet-breadcrumbs-(xlebnyie-kroshki)-na-yii-2.x).
Например, у Вас товары по категориям-подкатегориям. Нужно в представлении вывести шаблон на основе массива ссылок-названий, эти ссылки и названия нужно определять самостоятельно, т.е. это фактически ручное управление. Т.е. у Вас например Nokia 7310, Вы ставите название последним элементом массива без указания ссылки, находите родительскую подкатегорию через запрос в БД и категорию (например выходит подкатегория Nokia, категория Телефоны) и это все Вы должны добавить в массив, который нужно передать классу-обработчику, который через какой-то метод отдает шаблон на основе полученных данных.
Все это должно происходить в экшене или отображении, и для каждого типа страниц нужно определять свои правила. Например, на уровне подкатегории без ссылки уже будет название самой подкатегории, конкретного телефона не будет, и т.д.

**Но...**
Скопирую свой комментарий:

Возможно не совсем корректно с моей стороны, т.к. я не гуру PHP и с PHP не работаю уже больше года, но лучше смотрите как сделано в классных проектах-фреймворках (Laravel5, Yii2, Symfony3), учитесь сразу делать правильно (конечно прям сразу не получится, но всё же). Все равно в реальных проектах вы с вероятностью 95% будете использовать какой-то фреймворк. Я за 5 лет ниразу не использовал самописные системы. Разобраться с PHP Вы сможете и на основе фреймворка. Если сложно - подтяните ООП, потом опять за фреймворк)

Из этих 3-х фреймворков Symfony будет сложноват для начального обучения, но советую посвятить ему как-нибудь время. Там можно увидеть немного другую реализацию привычных вещей.

**P.S.** Еще в похожих нашел [такой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/87076/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%85%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-php?rq=1). Может тоже будет полезен.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно вам подойдет самый простой способ как на OpenCart

```
    $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

    $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'text' => $this->language->get('text_home'),
        'href' => $this->url->link('common/home')
    );
```

во вьюхе перебираете.

Дело в том, что этот способ один из наиболее точных, т.к вы можете напрямую корректировать данные. И доля ошибки маловероятна.